# How to approach management about switching roles in company

Tags: management, job-satisfaction

I don't know how to go about doing this. About a month and a half ago we were asked what role we wanted within the company, I'm a developer and I chose Professional Services since up to this point that's basically what I've been doing is coding custom pages for clients, custom implementations, etc. I love it, it's what I went to school for, everything about coding is great (which is basically all they do over on the Research and Dev side of the company). I was also specifically told that I would still be a developer on the PS side of the company.

Over the last couple of weeks I've been getting more and more support tickets coming my way as they wean one of the R & D guys off of support, I'll be the one that has to do client upgrades etc from what I've been told as well. It seems like my role is turning more from "Programmer/Analyst" to "Tier Two Support Analyst". This isn't what I want, I feel like I was sort of mislead (albeit not intentionally) or misunderstood what exactly my role would be.

I was let go from my previous job, which was entirely support, because my support there was lacking, I'm really not suited to support. I don't want support to be jeopardizing my job with this company either, I am much better suited to coding.

We're currently interviewing people to fill roles on both sides of the fence (R&D and PS), is there a way I can go about asking the management about them switching me over to R&D? I feel like it would disrupt some of their interview process by doing this however, what's the right way to go about this without stepping on too many toes? So to speak.

Comment: Turns out things were fine, I was just at a couple weeks where I was doing a lot of support issues. I'm still very much a developer though :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start here:

> Boss, do you have a minute?

Then see where this leads:

> The work that's coming my way isn't in line with my career goals.  It
>   seems like I'm getting support work when I really want to be
>   programming.  What can I do to get into R&D?

Your boss should then tell you exactly what you need to get into that department or at least put you on the right path.